# jQuery: select the last 4 items in the list

Tags: jquery, css, list

I have a list of images/ text links,

```
<ul>
<li>link 1</li>
<li>link 2</li>
<li>link 3</li>
<li>link 4</li>

<li>link 5</li>
<li>link 6</li>
<li>link 7</li>
<li>link 8</li>
</ul>
```

and I style the list in my .css file,

```
li {
  float:left;
  margin:0px 5px 5px 0px; 
}
```

but then I want the last 4 items in the list to be displayed without the 5px space at their margin bottom. so I would like to use jQuery to select these last 4 item and change their css style to marginBottom:0px;

The problem is that this is how jQuery selects the last item:

```
li:last
```

but what about the last 4? or maybe the last 5, or 6?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$('li').slice(-4).css('color', 'red')
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GJLYK/1/)

Comment: the above code will return the last five elements, as slice is 0 based.

Comment: Interesting. Did you try the example? Seems to be 0 based starting from the beginning. `$('li').slice(-4).length` >> 4

Comment: @super, it selects the last four because it is negative. So it counts 4 from the end..

Comment: You made my day, bro!

Answer (score 2):

```
var e = $('li').slice(-4).css('margin-bottom', '0px');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vF9kL/2/)

Answer (score 1):

use `:gt()`
As in:

```
var n = $('ul').size();
var lastFour = $('li:gt(' + n-5 + ')');
```

http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter method

```
var elems = $('ul li');
elems.filter(function(idx){
     /* we use 5  because the index starts at 0 */
     return idx > elems.length-5; 
}).css('margin-bottom','0px');
```

Demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Cw3uu/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').slice(-4).addClass('last-li-items');
```

Then in your css:

```
.last-li-items {
    margin-bottom:0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.slice()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)

```
$('li').slice(-4)
```

Or, you can use jQuery's [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```
var size = $('li').size();
$('li:gt('+(size-5)+')');
```

Comment: should be -4 (*OP wants the last 4*)

Comment: @Gaby: "but what about the last 4? or maybe the last 5, or 6?"

Comment: I just mean that your two examples select different things.. first selects last 5, second selects last 4

Comment: @Gaby: My bad, fixed that.  :-P

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this `$("li").slice(-5);`

Comment: The number doen't matter,does it?

Comment: @Jishny, not really.. *got carried away because from the two methods suggested one using a zero based needs a different number than this method.*