# Select n:th child from the bottom with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery: select the last 4 items in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617634/jquery-select-the-last-4-items-in-the-list)

jQuery has the nth-child psuedo-class, but is there a way to select the say 3:rd to last child ?

Comment: Did sizzle remove support for `:nth-last-of-type`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you don't necessarily need to use the `:nth-child()` notation, you could use a negative index with `eq()`:

```
$(selector).eq(-3);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4Y3Rb/).

Or, in compliant browsers, you could simply use CSS:

```
elementSelector:nth-last-child(3) {
    /* CSS declaration block */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4Y3Rb/1/) (tested, and confirmed-working, in Chromium 19/Ubuntu 11.04).

The CSS-selector, presumably thanks to `document.querySelector()`/`document.querySelectorAll()`, is also available as a selector in jQuery:

```
$('li:nth-last-child(3)').css('background-color','#f90');​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4Y3Rb/2/)

References:

- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Comment: jQuery from what I know, makes all selectors available cross-browser, so I think these would all work well!