# Jquery function that removes the border bottom from the last 4 LI's from an UL list

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list:

```
<div class="toplist">
    <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am thinking of a jquery code which removes the li border for the last 4 items.

Any ideas?

```
function toplist(){
$('.toplist ul li').css("border-bottom", "none");
}
```

Ty

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery: select the last 4 items in the list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617634/jquery-select-the-last-4-items-in-the-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get last elements:

```
function toplist(){
    $('.toplist ul li').slice(-4).css("border-bottom", "none");
}
```

> **.slice( start [, end] )**
>
> **start** An integer indicating the 0-based
>   position at which the elements begin to be selected. If negative, it
>   indicates an offset from the end of the set.
>
> **end** An integer indicating
>   the 0-based position at which the elements stop being selected. If
>   negative, it indicates an offset from the end of the set. If omitted,
>   the range continues until the end of the set.